# Strange issue in converting Feet and Inches to Centimeter and Vice Versa

Tags: java, math

```
public static double convertFeetandInchesToCentimeter(String feet, String inches) {
    double heightInFeet = 0;
    double heightInInches = 0;
    try {
        if (feet != null && feet.trim().length() != 0) {
            heightInFeet = Double.parseDouble(feet);
        }
        if (inches != null && inches.trim().length() != 0) {
            heightInInches = Double.parseDouble(inches);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

    }
    return (heightInFeet * 30.48) + (heightInInches * 2.54);
}
```

Above is the function for converting Feet and Inches to Centimeter.Below is the function for converting Centimeter back to Feet and Inches.

```
public static String convertCentimeterToHeight(double d) {
    int feetPart = 0;
    int inchesPart = 0;
    if (String.valueOf(d) != null && String.valueOf(d).trim().length() != 0) {
        feetPart = (int) Math.floor((d / 2.54) / 12);
        inchesPart = (int) Math.ceil((d / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));
    }
    return String.format("%d' %d''", feetPart, inchesPart);
}
```

I have a problem when i enter normal values like `5 Feet and 6 Inches`, its converting perfectly to centimeter and again it gets converted back to 5 Feet and 6 Inches.

> The **Problem** is when i convert 1 Feet and 1 inches or 2 Feet and 2
>   inches, its getting converted back to 1 Feet 2 inches and 2 Feet 3
>   inches.

Comment: 1) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I agree very much with @AndrewThompson here. While the `Exception` was not key to solving this issue (as the second function was the problem, not the first), it's always a good idea to have stack trace output for debugging. SSCCE's are invaluable on StackOverflow and I recommend that you use them in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe:

```
inchesPart = (int) Math.ceil((d / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));
```

Should be:

```
inchesPart = (int) Math.floor((d / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));
```

Comment: According to the original post, 1 ft / 1 in turn to be 1 ft / 2 in, I've done the calculus by hand, and it appears that for this case `feetPart = 1` but then `inchesPart = (int) Math.ceil((d / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));` is 2 that mean `(int) Math.ceil(1)` => 2 for some odd reason

Comment: @Jaay Floating point numbers work that way. "1" in this case is 1.000000? where ?is some series of digits, not all zero. Thus "1" > 1, and so Math.ceil("1") = 2.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewThompson. I see a lot of your posts on here and appreciate your comments and feedback throughout the site.

Answer (score 3):

I ran the following code

```
public class FeetInches{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        double d = convertFeetandInchesToCentimeter("1","1");

        String back_again = convertCentimeterToHeight(d);

        System.out.println(back_again);


    }

    public static double convertFeetandInchesToCentimeter(String feet, String inches) {
        double heightInFeet = 0;
        double heightInInches = 0;
        try {
        if (feet != null && feet.trim().length() != 0) {
            heightInFeet = Double.parseDouble(feet);
        }
        if (inches != null && inches.trim().length() != 0) {
            heightInInches = Double.parseDouble(inches);
        }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

        }
        return (heightInFeet * 30.48) + (heightInInches * 2.54);
    }


    public static String convertCentimeterToHeight(double d) {
        int feetPart = 0;
        int inchesPart = 0;
        if (String.valueOf(d) != null && String.valueOf(d).trim().length() != 0) {
        feetPart = (int) Math.floor((d / 2.54) / 12);
        System.out.println((d / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));
        inchesPart = (int) Math.ceil((d / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));
        }
        return String.format("%d' %d''", feetPart, inchesPart);
    }


}
```

And got

```
1.0000000000000018
1' 2''
```

By using the ceiling function you are rounding up to 2 when you really want to be rounding down to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the way java handles floating point numbers.

```
inchesPart = (int) Math.ceil(Math.round((d / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12)));
```

or

```
inchesPart = (int) Math.floor((d / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));
```

In case of input 2,2 the original value of inchesPart is 2.0000000000000036 -> ceil ->3

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with you're code is that you're not using the same rounding function for each part :

```
int feetPart = (int) Math.floor((d / 2.54) / 12);
                          ^^^^^
int inchesPart = (int) Math.ceil((d / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12));
                            ^^^^
```

You should also do the rounding before the decomposition in order to obtain consistent results :

```
int feetPart = ((int) Math.round(d / 2.54)) / 12;
int inchesPart = ((int) Math.round((d / 2.54)) - (feetPart * 12);
```

Which could be factorized to:

```
int inches = (int) Math.round(d / 2.54);
int feetPart = inches / 12;
int inchesPart = inches  - (feetPart * 12);
```

Or since `( inches - ( ( inches / 12 ) * 12) ) == ( inches % 12 )`:

```
int inches = (int) Math.round(d / 2.54);
feetPart = inches / 12;
inchesPart = inches % 12;
```

You can interchange `Math.round` with `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` depending on the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old may be useful for someone else (Kotlin version)

```
  fun feetToCentimeter(feetval: String): String {
        var heightInFeet = 0.0
        var heightInInches = 0.0
        var feet = ""
        var inches = ""
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(feetval)) {
            if (feetval.contains("'")) {
                feet = feetval.substring(0, feetval.indexOf("'"))
            }
            if (feetval.contains("\"")) {
                inches = feetval.substring(feetval.indexOf("'") + 1, feetval.indexOf("\""))
            }
        }
        try {
            if (feet.trim { it <= ' ' }.isNotEmpty()) {
                heightInFeet = feet.toDouble()
            }
            if (inches.trim { it <= ' ' }.isNotEmpty()) {
                heightInInches = inches.toDouble()
            }
        } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
        }

        return (((heightInFeet * 12.0) + heightInInches) * 2.54).toString()
    }

    fun centimeterToFeet(centemeter: String?): String {
        var feetPart = 0
        var inchesPart = 0
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(centemeter)) {
            val dCentimeter = java.lang.Double.valueOf(centemeter!!)
            feetPart = Math.floor((dCentimeter / 2.54) / 12).toInt()
            println(dCentimeter / 2.54 - feetPart * 12)
            inchesPart = Math.floor((dCentimeter / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12)).toInt()
        }
        return String.format("%d' %d\"", feetPart, inchesPart)
    }
```