# Change person height to centimeter on click of ToggleButton

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` with a `ToggleButton` with option feet/inch and centimeters. If a user selects option feet/inches and enter his height. Now I want if user selects centimeters option from `ToggleButton` then it should automatically change his height to centimeters.

I have tried something like this:

```
     public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnCm:
                toggleHeightButton(R.id.btnCm,R.id.btnFeet,false);
                break;
            case R.id.btnFeet:
                toggleHeightButton(R.id.btnFeet,R.id.btnCm,true);
                enter_height.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(enter_height));
                break;
            case R.id.btnKg:
                toggleweightButton(R.id.btnKg,R.id.btnpound,false);
                break;
            case R.id.btnpound:
                toggleweightButton(R.id.btnpound,R.id.btnKg,true);
                break;

        }
    }

    public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private EditText mEditText;
    public CustomTextWatcher(EditText enter_height) {
        mEditText = enter_height;
    }



     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int count = s.length();
        String str = s.toString();
        if (count == 1) {
            str = str + "'";
        } else if (count == 2) {
            return;
        } else if (count == 3) {
            str = str + "\"";
        } else if ((count > 4) && (str.charAt(str.length() - 1) != '\"') ){
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 2) + str.charAt(str.length() - 1)
                    + "\"";
        } else {
            return;
        }

        mEditText.setText(str);
        mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length());
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me from here how can I approach. I also wanted to validate the height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange issue in converting Feet and Inches to Centimeter and Vice Versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062094/strange-issue-in-converting-feet-and-inches-to-centimeter-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

In your onToggleListener/onClickListener()

```
//toCm is true if converting from inches to centimeters
private void toggleHeight(int height, boolean toCm) {

    if (height > 0) {
        if (toCm) {
            //2.54cm is equal to 1inch
            return height / 2.54;
        } else {
            return height * 2.54.
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can set your mEditText to the new height which will display it to the user.

There will be some precision loss but seeing as how you simply want to display this to the user, this should work just fine.